# Youtube API empty channels list by categoryId

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

On Youtube API manual for Channels method  [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

categoryId parameter is described as "YouTube guide category".

I've got guide categories list by

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=RU&key=cannot_publish_my_api_key_here
```

But when I'm trying to get channels list by id of every guide category from that list, for example,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?categoryId=GCTmV3cyAmIFBvbGl0aWNz&key=&part=snippet
```

I'm always getting an empty result

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [

  ]
}
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: I just ran it with your category id and i got 30 items.

Comment: Thank! Maybe something wrong with my api key settings or permissions level.

Comment: @DaImTo I am calling above API using API_KEY , still getting same response.. Can you help how to short-out that issue...

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&categoryId=GCQmVhdXR5ICYgRmFzaGlvbg&key=(API_KEY)